# How do I implement an exception handler for strings and doubles in my bubble sort?

Tags: c++, string, exception, bubble-sort

```
        #include <iostream>
       #include<conio.h>
       using namespace std;

       int main()
       {

       int hold;
       int swapNumber=0;
       int compare=0;
       int array[10];

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
       {
        cout<<"Enter 10 numbers: "<<endl;
        cin>>array[i]; 
} 
cout<<endl; 

// what user inputed
cout<<"Originally entered array by the user is: "<<endl;

for(int k=0; k<10; k++)
{
    cout<<array[k];
    cout<<endl; 
} 
cout<<endl;

//begin bubblesort method
for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
{

    for(int k=0; k<9; k++)
{
        compare++;
        if(array[k]>array[k+1])
{
            hold=array[k];
            array[k]=array[k+1];
            array[k+1]=hold; 
            swapNumber++;//adding swap count by 1
            }//end of if
        } //end of for j
    } // end of for i

//when sorted sm to large
cout<<"Sorted Array is: "<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    cout<<array[i]<<endl; 
} 

//how many times numbers are swapped
cout<<"Number of times Swapped: "<<swapNumber<<endl;

//how ,many times numbers are compared
cout<<"Number of times Compared: "<<compare<<endl;

getch();
}
```

My assignment is to add an exception handler which states "Error! ONLY INTEGER INPUT ALLOWED ".The handler is supposed to catch doubles and strings. I've tried try and catch method but i don't know quite where to place it so that it'll work. I've also read about the catch all method, which seems like what i need to do. I've just now completed my counter methods for swap and comparisons which I do believe are working fine.

Comment: Your sort should be in its own function with typed parameters. In that case, it's impossible for it receive non-integers as the conversion is done before hand. In other words, this exception should be thrown by the input part of your code and not by the sort itself, (which is unclear in your title). Second, why does your handler need to catch a double? What would it do with it? Throwing number data types is frowned upon because they lack context. At least a string, presumably, can be printed with a relevant message.

Comment: well i can use the double as a single digit unit but i have tried setprecision and it still won't work. what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int hold, swapNumber = 0, compare = 0, array[10];
    const string Error = "Error! ONLY INTEGER INPUT ALLOWED!";

    cout << "Enter 10 numbers: " << endl;
    try
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            cin >> array[i];
            if ( !cin ) // Error in reading input stream
            {
                throw Error;
            }
        }
    }
    catch ( const string& E )
    {
        cout << E << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Originally entered array by the user is: " << endl;
    for ( int k = 0; k < 10; k++ )
    {
        cout << array[k] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
    {
        for ( int k = 0; k < 9; k++ )
        {
            compare++;
            if ( array[k] > array[k + 1] )
            {
                hold = array[k];
                array[k] = array[k + 1];
                array[k + 1] = hold;
                swapNumber++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Sorted Array is: " << endl;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Number of times Swapped: " << swapNumber << endl;
    cout << "Number of times Compared: " << compare << endl;

    getch();
}
```

Comment: i tried to use your adjustments but i keep getting a no operator found error is there some library i'm missing

Comment: i now see what you were doing thanks for guiding me to the right path

Comment: I am happy that I could be of any help to you ! You can upvote and accept my answer if it was all that you were looking for.